# Change size of taskbar applet

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

I really love my task bar, but one annoying thing is the size of this applet  (or how do you call it?):

[image: How to resize this screen?]

It shows only 5 devices, while I've got many more devices. I've got a very large screen, so I'de like to have this balloon larger. How can I adjust the height of it?

I'm using Kubuntu 16.04 and Plasma 5.6.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Resize plasma popups**

Plasma popups ( calendar, kickoff, device notifier, ... ) can be resized by holding  <kbd>Alt</kbd> key pressed and dragging with the Right Mouse Button.

[image]

The size will reset when the plasmashell restarts (logout): https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=332512